# How to implement predictive input for custom Android keyboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard

I am developing a custom keyboard on Android. I want to implement predictive input. For example, when the user types "He", the keyboard suggests the following words "He", "Hello", "Hey" and etc. to the user. I know that I need a huge dictionary with word frequency and diff calculation, but this is too long.

1. Is it possible to do this using native Android libraries?
2. Are there any ready made libraries?

[image]

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Yes, you can check this API https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill   
The only problem I didn't solve was that some autofill callbacks never worked on Sumsung devices. It looks like they have changed this API and are not going to fix it. But I'm not sure about the current situation.

Comment: Hi @MaxAstin, thanks for giving me the link but I am looking for the proper suggestions